# Total of Custom Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to get the total of the "Conversion" column for each "AccountDescName".

However, the expression inside is also grouped by the statdate.

[image]

How would I go about getting the total of the conversions.

[image]

When I paste that same expression in a row below, it gives me a different number.

Comment: What is the expression in the conversions textbox (selected in the first image)?

Comment: =iif(sum(Fields!AllConversions.Value)>0,FormatNumber(Sum(Fields!AllConversions.Value)/count(Fields!ConversionTypeName.Value),2),"")



I have 5 rows of the same conversionType and the conversionValue. So when it sums for the date, I need to divide it out by the count of same conversionType. But when it does the same calculation over a range of dates, it gets messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by keeping my data split up by rows and removing duplicates.
Did not do any aggregation in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a subtotal by account, you'll want to add a new row that is inside that group, but outside the StatDate group. Right-click on the field that was highlighted in your first screenshot. Select "Insert Row" -> "Outside Group - Below". This new row is where your subtotal will go. You can usually copy the same expression here and it will evaluate within its new scope.

For a grand total, you would follow similar steps, but you would insert the row outside the account group. This would result in one final row at the end of the entire table.

Comment: This makes sense. However, my expression is dependant on statdate, and if I take it out of the scope, the aggregation doesn't give me a proper value. So instead of 105+108+60, I would get 9000 due to the nature of the data structure.

Is there a way to just sum the values of certain cells?

Comment: If your structure includes multiple copies of each value, you can add a `ROW_NUMBER` windowed function to your query to identify the unique fields. That way you can just aggregate those to get the correct number at this scope. It works like a charm.